# Update input fields one at a time without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a mixture of input fields, textareas and combo boxes which I would like to be able to update one at a time (without page refresh) but I am not quite sure how to approach this. When update is clicked it should update the MySQL Database respectively. I know how to update all of them at the same time but I am trying to avoid using this method. Every input, textarea, combo has a input type submit next to them to get me started.
This is part of the html file that I am referring too.

```
<form action="" class="customform" method="post" id="file-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                
                <h5>Set competition name</h5>
                <input type="text" id="Gamename" name="Gamename" value="<?php echo $GameName; ?>" size="400" style="max-width: 410px">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Update1" type="submit" value="Update" style="width: auto;">
                
                <h5>Set competition date & time</h5>
                <input type="text" id="demo" name="timedate" value="<?php echo $sdate; ?>" size="200" style="max-width: 210px">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Update2" type="submit" value="Update" style="width: auto;">
```

What would be the best way to achieve this? Would I need to use Ajax, Javascript or Jquery? I am not asking for all the code to be written for me, just some guidance on how to approach it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was done by ajax full code is here with all guidance.

https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@sogata/how-to-update-data-mysql-from-php-without-reload-page-using-jquery-ajax

```
               $.ajax({
                        url:'update.php',
                        method:'POST',
                        data:{
                            name:name,
                            ctgr:ctgr
                        },
                        success:function(response){
                            alert(response);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: That is just what I was looking for and also shows me how to save to the db as well. perfect.

Comment: well come i am happy

Answer (score 3):

Try:

**HTML**

```
<div id="output"></div> // This is where response (res/err) will be showed
```

**JS**

```
var form = document.getElementById("file-upload-form");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

form.onsubmit = () => {
    fetch("your_page.php", {
            method: "POST",
            body: new FormData(form)
        })
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => {
            output.innerHTML = res;
        })
        .catch((err) => output.innerHTML = err);
    return false;
};
```

You don't need jQuery for such a simple task.